# Accessing video frames in specific order MATLAB

Tags: matlab, video

i'm using matlab for video processing, vehicle plate detection, this is my code for show video in frame. that code is process all frame in 1 video

```
   for dataframe=1:obj.NumberOfFrames
        LGi=read(obj,dataframe);

    axes(handles.mpengujianavideo);
    set(imshow(insertObjectAnnotation(LGi, 'rectangle', deteksipelat,'Plat')));
    title(strcat('Frame ke-',mat2str(dataframe)));
```

the question is, how can i jumping frame, not process all frame, but just process every 3 frame in video??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for dataframe=1:3:obj.NumberOfFrames
    LGi=read(obj,dataframe);

axes(handles.mpengujianavideo);
set(imshow(insertObjectAnnotation(LGi, 'rectangle', deteksipelat,'Plat')));
title(strcat('Frame ke-',mat2str(dataframe)));
```